# При вызове функции выводит <function result.<locals>.func2 at 0x7f4c18cef158>

Tags: python, функции

```
def result(a, b, c):

    def func1(a, b):
        return a * b

    def func2(func1, c):
        return func1 * c

    return func2

print(result(2, 3, 4))
```

Вроде как должен вернуть число 12, но выводит строку <function result..func2 at 0x7f4c18cef158>.
Пытался менять способы вывода, но увы. Кажется, что задача проста и ответ на нее также прост, но никак не могу сообразить в чем дело.

Comment: Надо вызвать функцию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def result(a, b, c):

    def func1():
        return a * b

    def func2():
        return func1() * c

    return func2()

print(result(2, 3, 4))
```

либо:

```
def result(a, b, c):

    def func1():
        return a * b

    def func2():
        return func1() * c

    return func2

n = result(2, 3, 4)
print(n())
```

вывод в обоих случаях:

> `24`

Comment: Да, 24)) Помогло, благодарю!!

Comment: @Lebovski если вам мой ответ помог то пожалуйста примите его(галочка слева от ответа)